# Six-piece mechanical puzzle with multiply-pointed pieces which fit into a concave polyhedron

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

[image]

I need help identifying this mechanical puzzle that consists of 6 pieces (see image) which I have to fit together into a sort of concave polyhedron.

Comment: Why does this have a "needs attribution" close vote? The asker might not know where the puzzle is from; indeed the question is asking us to identify the puzzle. We're not being asked to solve, just identify. This kind of question (identify puzzle off pictures) is acceptable here - see other [mechanical puzzle identification requests](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puzzle-identification+mechanical-puzzles).

Comment: I have no other information then provided in the picture, I just found the 6 pieces by themselves while cleaning out my room (no box, and none of the pieces have any logos or identifying marks). The 6 pieces are not identical, there are the 4 "main" ones at the top, then the other 2 have slight variations that make them different (as well as the fact that 3 are "left-facing" and 3 are "right-facing". I can try to provide a higher quality image (with better lighting) if that would help.

Comment: Yes, better lighting may help. Please also consider doing a close-up (or close-ups, of different angles if necessary) of each of the three different piece shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This puzzle was designed by Stewart Coffin, and he called it the Star of David puzzle. It is a variation on the classic diagonal burr puzzle. The aim is to put the pieces together into a symmetric shape, and there are three distinct symmetric shapes you can make that have 3-fold rotational symmetry. One of these shapes looks like a 6-pointed star from one direction.

It has not been mass-produced, but only made in relatively small numbers by hand by puzzle craftspeople.

Here are some pictures taken from [John Rausch's site](https://johnrausch.com/PuzzleWorld/puz/star_of_david.htm):

[image]
[image]

Nowadays you can [3D-print puzzles](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4748156) like this.

Comment: Wow! This is really incredible, that you were able to identify it if it's so rarely produced- how were you able to find it?

Comment: @IsaacMammel I thought it had to be one of Stewart Coffin's designs. I bought a copy of his book [The Puzzling World of Polyhedral Dissections](https://johnrausch.com/PuzzlingWorld/) thirty years ago, and that book inspired hundreds of puzzle makers to design and produce many new assembly puzzles since then. I found the name of the puzzle eventually by doing an image search for some combination of "diagonal burr" and Coffin.